# How to tune PID output limiter

Tags: pid-controller

Firstly, I am a newby guy on PID control or any other control techniques. After I reviewed documentaries and C source files on the net. There is an issue on my mind.
PID blocks in some documantaries shows that PID output feeds the PLANT directly.
In my application, my PID' input is Vout, and I control the PWM frequencies of mosfets.
So, If I feed mosfets directly with the PID output ( assume that I limit also), do I do it right ?
Because I find this wrong.

According to me PID output is a value that varies between negative and positive edges.
This value should be added to the actual frequency value ( this is raw value that will be written into PWM registers)and then, a limiter should be applied for this sum.

If my approach is okay then, how specify the limiter for PID output.

Please do not judge me If I say bullshit things.

Answer (score 0):

You can try both and see which gives better results. If you are adding an offset, you are likely to have a low or zero P term.

Your limits are entirely based on the application. For example, small electronics need very short, rapid pulses. Something like a heating element will need longer pulses. You should find the voltage range you want, and then experimentally find limits that prevent you from going outside this range with a voltmeter once your PID is tuned.